# How to handle True, False or NULL in where clause

Tags: sql

How can I reduce this to only one where statement
@state as bit

```
IF @state IS NULL
    SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE name IS NULL
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE name = @state
```

I wish I could compare True, False or NULL in one select statement

Comment: What is wrong with your current statement?  It makes sense to me.

Comment: I know it works but i wish i can do one line..this is just a sample the actual query is longer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this not work?

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL 
WHERE (@state is null and name is null) or 
      (name = @state)
```

Another approach would be to use `coalesce` on both conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If using MySQL, here is a simpler way:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE name <=> @state;
```